# Export styled pandas df with bar charts as png

Tags: python, pandas, imgkit

I would like to export a pandas df with barcharts (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html#Bar-charts) using imgkit as follows but the barcharts are not included in the final pdf.

[image]

I tried to pass the css separately to webkit with the `css=<filename>` kwarg without success. Other styled pd.DataFrames from the style manual seem to work.

Does anybody see why the CSS is not applied? Any alternatives to export styled tables to png?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(24)
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.linspace(1, 10, 10)})
df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4), columns=list('BCDE'))],
               axis=1)
df.iloc[3, 3] = np.nan
df.iloc[0, 2] = np.nan

s = df.style.bar(subset=['A', 'B'], align='mid', color=['#d65f5f', '#5fba7d'])
html = s.render()

import imgkit
imgkit.from_string(html, 'styled_table3.png')
```

Comment: Hi Bjonen, have you found a solution to this? I want to do this as well and the only solution that worked was from here:https://blog.ouseful.info/2019/01/16/converting-pandas-generated-html-data-tables-to-png-images/. It works as a standalone solution, but doesn't integrate well with dash as part of webapp.

Comment: The automated part that takes a snapshot of the styled dataframe rendered in a web-browser, causes the the rest of the web-app to reset in some way i don't understand. I've played with imagekit encoding options, but don't think that this is the issue. There is some custom css in the barcharts that just doesn't translate.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I haven't found a solution either.